# Is there a way to throttle the bandwidth using the ruby library net:scp?

Tags: ruby

I can't find any documentation about this anywhere. I've done a ton of google searching as well.  I"m really hoping there is a way to throttle the bandwidth like you can natively with scp in Linux.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I mean, would something like this work?

**ssh.scp.download!(source, target, :recursive => true, -l => 2)**

Comment: So it looks like there is not a way.  According to the options you can pass to the command, that is not one of them.  What do you think would be the easiest way to get this to work?  Modify the net:scp source?  That causes some issues though for people in my organization wanting to use my app.  I'd have to upload the new net:scp gem to some public repository wouldn't I?

Comment: There's an open PR to add this feature https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp/pull/53, but it was opened 2 years ago so apparently the project is not maintained anymore.